# binance api ошибка 'code': -1102, 'msg': "Mandatory parameter 'timestamp' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите, не могу найти причину ошибки. Проблема с передачей часовой метки. Такой подход для https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order работает, но для https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/order уже не работает. Вот код "шредингера"

```
import ssl
import time
import json
import urllib
import hmac, hashlib
import requests

from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
class Binance():

    methods = {'createOrder':      {'url': 'fapi/v1/order', 'method': 'POST', 'private': True}}

    def __init__(self, API_KEY, API_SECRET):
        self.API_KEY = API_KEY
        self.API_SECRET = bytearray(API_SECRET, encoding='utf-8')

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            kwargs.update(command=name)
            return self.call_api(**kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def call_api(self, **kwargs):
        command = kwargs.pop('command')
        api_url = 'https://fapi.binance.com/' + self.methods[command]['url']

        payload = kwargs
        headers = {}

        payload_str = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
        if self.methods[command]['private']:
            payload.update({'timestamp': int(time.time()) * 1000})
            payload_str = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode('utf-8')
            sign = hmac.new(
                key=self.API_SECRET,
                msg=payload_str,
                digestmod=hashlib.sha256
            ).hexdigest()

            payload_str = payload_str.decode("utf-8") + "&signature="+str(sign) 
            headers = {"X-MBX-APIKEY": self.API_KEY}

        response = requests.request(method=self.methods[command]['method'], url=api_url, data="" if self.methods[command]['method'] == 'GET' else payload_str, headers=headers)
        return response.json()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    binance = Binance('','')
    print(binance.createOrder(symbol="BTCUSDT", quantity=1, side="BUY", type="MARKET"))
```

Документация binance
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#new-order-trade

Comment: pip install python-binance

Comment: https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance

Comment: Чужой велосипед всегда круче, особенно, если он ездит!

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с этой же проблемой.
Решением было передача данных не через `data`, а через `params`, вне зависимости от метода (`GET`, `POST`, ...):

```
response = requests.request(..., params=payload_str, ...)
```